# Can I host my API in Heroku, and access it from GitHub Pages?

Tags: javascript, api, heroku, github-pages

I seem to be hitting a lot of walls due to the safety precautions taken by browsers to avoid XSS attacks.

Basically I have some exposed api on Heroku, ie: `myapi.herokuapp.com/get/stories` but when trying to make such requests from a plain `Client.html` file on my Desktop, say via `XMLHttpRequest` or `WebSocket`, I get `NS_ERROR_DOM_BAD_URI` or variants thereof.

Am I trying to do something nonsensical?

Comment: You just need to use Access-Control-Allow-Origin and other headers in your app. If you use express.js then check npm 'cors' module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, it's not nonsensical. You should be able to access it just fine if you have the API and client configured for such requests.  For reference, here are some of my (working) settings, with my API hosted on Heroku and accessible from localhost

API (backend)

```
server.connection {
  port: process.env.PORT
  routes:
    cors:
      origin: ['*']
      credentials: true
      additionalHeaders: ['X-Requested-With']
}
```

Angular (frontend)

```
angular.module('app.core').config ($locationProvider, $stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider, $cookiesProvider) ->
  $locationProvider.html5Mode true

  ## Configure CORS
  $httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true
  $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true
  delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"]
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["Accept"] = "application/json"
  $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["Content-Type"] = "application/json"
  # $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = "XMLHttpRequest"
```